# Table split and set significant digits in MATLAB Report Generator

Tags: matlab

I am trying to split a table and set each cell significant digits to 2 using MATLAB Report Generator. I read the examples in Matlab site and look on many previous questions including in this forum but still I do not know how to solve it. Any help will be appropriated:

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;

import mlreportgen.report.*
import mlreportgen.dom.*
import mlreportgen.utils.*
    
dataInput = webread('https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/lead_shot.csv');
  
colIsNum = varfun(@isnumeric, dataInput,'OutputFormat','uniform');
table_data = dataInput; % keep original, more precise data
table_data{:,colIsNum} = round(dataInput{:,colIsNum},2)
 
rpt = mlreportgen.report.Report("Sliced Table",'pdf');
open(rpt);

chapter = Chapter();
table = FormalTable(table_data);
table.Border = 'Solid';
table.RowSep = 'Solid';
table.ColSep = 'Solid';

para = Paragraph(['Data table']);
para.Style = {OuterMargin('0in','0in','0in','12pt')};
para.FontSize = '10pt';
add(chapter,para)

slicer = TableSlicer("Table",table,"MaxCols",4,"RepeatCols",1);
totcols = slicer.MaxCols - slicer.RepeatCols;
slices = slicer.slice();
for slice=slices
     str = sprintf('%d repeating column and up to %d more columns',...
          slicer.RepeatCols,totcols);
     para = Paragraph(str);
     para.Bold = true;
     add(chapter,para)
     add(chapter,slice.Table)
end
 
add(rpt,chapter)
 
close(rpt)
rptview(rpt)
```

Comment: You could try converting the numeric columns to cell arrays of chars, so each element is actually a string with whatever place value you want. Then there can be no other interpretation (i.e. additional decimal places) during the report generation.

Comment: Thanks but the string field in generated report are appearing with 'numeric'. For example:  '#TriBall'